# How to set correctly the relative position for Jquery Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with my drag and drop function

This is my Canvas

```
<canvas id="note" class="lego"
width="10" height="20">
</canvas>
```

My Drag and drop create a clone and place it in my div (div ID is "section"), after the drop i remove his class "lego" and add a new one named "legopiazzato"

If i leave the style of the clone with "position : absolute" there is no problem.

But i need relative, because i want the top/left cordinates on the div and not the top/left cordinates on the document.

The problem is: with relative, after the drop operation, he take the mouse position absolute and, with this, set the top/left of my clone in respect of the div (my clone is placed in a different location than where I left with the drop operation)

I thought to subtract this absolute cordinates, but I don't know exactly how to do

How can i fix??

This is my DraganDrop:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var x = null;



$(".lego").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: "invalid",
    tolerance: "pointer",

    stop: function (e, ui) {

            $(".ui-draggable-dragging").addClass("legopiazzato");


            $(".ui-draggable-dragging").removeClass("lego");

            $(".ui-draggable-dragging").dblclick(function() {
            $(this).remove();
            });

            $(".legopiazzato").draggable({
                cursor: 'move',
                grid: [ 1,1]
            });

    }
});

        $("#section").droppable({

            drop: function (e, ui) {

                if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                    x = ui.helper.clone();
                ui.helper.remove();

                console.log(ui.position.left);
                console.log(ui.position.top);

                x.draggable({
                    helper: 'original',
                    containment: '#section',
                    tolerance: 'fit'
                });
                x.appendTo('#section');

                }

            }

        });
});
```

Comment: If you keep position absolute and use `offset()` to calculate dragged element position and compare to the parent offset ones, the maths looks simple, no?! Anyway, you should provide a MCVE replicating your issue

Comment: absolute is not positioned with respect to the document if the parent div is position relative. So you can just add position: relative to the canvas maybe?